# If condition match, destroy array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to destroy array so it doesnt print if condition match

when I dump `var_dump($action)` I get result:

```
array(6) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(13) "visit-website"
  ["label"]=>
  string(7) "Website"
  ["icon"]=>
  string(10) "fa fa-link"
  ["title_l10n"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["locale"]=>
    string(5) "en_US"
  }
  ["class"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  string(9) "qa-6c92c1"
}
array(6) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(12) "leave-review"
  ["label"]=>
  string(14) "Leave a review"
  ["icon"]=>
  string(25) "icon-chat-bubble-square-1"
  ["title_l10n"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["locale"]=>
    string(5) "en_US"
  }
  ["class"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  string(9) "qa-df9b9a"
}
array(6) {
  ["action"]=>
  string(13) "test-today"
  ["label"]=>
  string(7) "Website"
  ["icon"]=>
  string(10) "fa fa-link"
  ["title_l10n"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["locale"]=>
    string(5) "en_US"
  }
  ["class"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["id"]=>
  string(9) "qa-6c92c1"
}
```

According to user role, I want to remove complete block where ["action"] = "test-today".

```
if($role !== 'administrator' || $role !== 'subscriber'){
    // if role is admin and subscriber remove block where ["action"] = "test-today"         
}
```

After success complete array will be deleted, at the end I will have two blocks

```
array(6) {
      ["action"]=>
      string(13) "test-today"
      ["label"]=>
      string(7) "Website"
      ["icon"]=>
      string(10) "fa fa-link"
      ["title_l10n"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["locale"]=>
        string(5) "en_US"
      }
      ["class"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["id"]=>
      string(9) "qa-6c92c1"
    }
```

What is the best way to perform this action, after removing I need to create new array holding same values except for block `["action"] = "test-today"`

Comment: your array doesn't have any index with `role`. so how can you check

Comment: it is related to user roles. array is created first, then I wanted to dropout array that contains ["action"]=>test-today

Comment: https://3v4l.org/CfmTZ

Comment: `if($role !== 'administrator' || $role !== 'subscriber')` -> this will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out providing `$action` is an array of array's. You can continue this way using your action array as normal

```
if($role !== 'administrator' &&  $role !== 'subscriber'){

    $action_column = array_column($action, 'action');

    if($key = array_search('test-today', $action_column)){

        unset($action[$key]);

    }
}
```